# Break down a 2-by-3 within within ANOVA into two 2-by-2 within within ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I have data that may be arrayed as a 2 (Time: A1 vs. A2) by 3 (Difficulty: B1, B2, B3) within-within factorial.

[image]

But I'm not interested in the comparison of difficulty B2 and B3 over Time. Is it appropriate that I analyse these data as two 2-by-2 within within ANOVA? i.e.:

[image]

Comment: Suggest you do the full 2-factor ANOVA with 2 levels of Time and 3 levels of Difficulty. If there turns out to be significant interaction between Time and Difficulty, look only at the multiple comparisons that are of interest. Also, it Difficulty is significant, you can confine attention to ad hoc comparisons of interest. The additional data may slightly increase the power of the various tests (by increasing DF for Error).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If, however, I chose to break up the factorial would this still be a statistically valid approach to data analysis?

Comment: Why would you want to? Does that somehow give you an answer that's more to you liking? If so, something strange is going on, and I'd be cautious about trusting that answer. // If you've been determined to break it up from the start, then why ask the question?